# Symfony by_reference not working as expected

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities:

- entityA
- entityB

mapping files:

```
Acme\Bundle\Entity\EntityA:
    type: entity
    table: entity_a
    repositoryClass: Acme\Bundle\Entity\EntityARepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
        created_on:
            type: datetime
    oneToMany:
        entity_b:
            targetEntity: Acme\Bundle\Entity\EntityB
            mappedBy: entity_a
            cascade: [persist, remove]
```

-

```
AgendaOnline\LessonBookBundle\Entity\EntityB:
    type: entity
    table: entity_b
    repositoryClass: Acme\Bundle\Entity\EntityBRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        fielda:
            type: integer
            length: 4
        fieldb:
            type: integer
            length: 4
        fieldc:
            type: integer
            length: 4
    manyToOne:
        entity_a:
            targetEntity: Acme\Bundle\Entity\EntityA
            inversedBy: entity_b
            nullable: false
```

(had to remove the real entity/column names, sorry)

Both of these have form classes:

EntityAType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('course', 'text')
            ->add('distance_table_data', 'collection', array(
                'type'      => new EntityBType($this->user, $this->entityManager),
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'prototype' => true,
                'options' => array('data_class' => 'Acme\Bundle\Entity\DistanceTableData'),
                )
            )
    ...
}
```

EntityBType: normal form class which renders the input fields for that class.

**What's not working?**

The Symfony docs state that when you're using by_reference, the add method for a certain column is used when that column is defined as a collection in the form. (Which is the case here). But the add method is never called in my case.

I might have 3-50 EntityB entities, but they get passed through the setter. Why is this happening?

Another problem:
So far as I can see are my relations good for my goal. EntityA has many EntityB and each EntityB has one EntityA. So I can expect that every EntityB I create in my form, should automatically be owned by the EntityA, which is not the case unfortunately.

In my EntityB code, I created a setter method: setEntityA, which is not called by Symfony. Why is this?

Comment: you have to write either add and remove method to have them called properly otherwise setter is called. moreover, how do you know those methods are not called? Last but not least, if you add into entityA (inversed side) you have to write "extra logic" to set A to B (in B of course) otherwise it will not be added

Comment: @DonCallisto addEntityB() and removeEntityB() are both present in my EntityA class. I know they're not called because of log function placed in those functions (also in the setter). Therefore I know the setter was called.

Comment: if you comment out setter what is called?

Comment: @DonCallisto found it! Symfony's Singularify function doesn't really work with my column name. It creates a weird singular state, which I didn't have in my entity and therefore called the setter instead.